# My MP3 tracks and videos can't play on Rhythmbox and Videos :(

Tags: 14.04

It show error that i need to install plug in and i don't know how to install them.
Please advice me how to do. I am new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras`

`ubuntu-restricted-extras` is a software package for Ubuntu that allows the user to install essential software which is not already included due to legal or copyright reasons.

It is a meta-package that installs:

- Support for MP3 and unencrypted DVD playback
- Microsoft TrueType core fonts
- Flash plugin
- codecs for common audio and video files

You can search for `ubuntu-restricted-extras` at the Ubuntu Software Center and Install via the software center

Or via terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), type:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```